# Why does my macOS always swap while sleeping?

Tags: macos, virtual-memory

Firstly, I had disabled swapping and hibernatemode is set to 0

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
```

(macOS SIP was disabled when executing the commands above)

Secondly, I use fs_usage to monitor fs usage log when sleep

```
sudo fs_usage -w >fsusage.log
```

sleep time is about 8 hours.

What I'm looking for is that the Mac will sleep, and just sleep, doing nothing. But I got a 135M `fsusage.log` file, and when I analyzed the log file, I got some weird results.

Here is the analysis result:

- The Mac always awake in certain periods of time.
- The system doesn't swapping when normal use, but swapping when sleep.

  1. The most written CALL

     ```
     PgOut[ST1P] : 3726 (MB)
     ```
  2. The `PgOut[ST1P]` CALL  write to the files:

     ```
     /dev/disk1  /private/var/vm/swapfile0 : 2443 (MB)
     /dev/disk1  /private/var/vm/swapfile1 : 1282 (MB)
     ```

PgOut size by timestamp:

05:55 : 1316 (MB)
06:56 : 1004 (MB)
07:12 : 143 (MB)
08:45 : 620 (MB)
08:46 : 25 (MB)
08:50 : 452 (MB)
08:51 : 163 (MB)

Sleep time is from 01:06 to 08:51

**My MBP information:**
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017)
macOS version: 10.12.6
memory size: 16GB

Comment: Did you disable Power Nap (... and I doubt that your Mac is really sleeping if you run `sudo fs_usage ...` in the background)?

Comment: Swap sounds like exactly what you want to have happen before sleeping. Minimize ram contents, speed the wake and let power nap have a cleaner set of RAM while sleeping and dark waking. This could be a feature and a good thing.

Comment: @klanomath Power Nap has disabled. I think it is really sleep, because the timestamp of the log is discontinuous, just at some point (About one minute each time).

Comment: @bmike I added "PgOut size by timestamp" in question description, It seems to be an swapping during sleep.

Comment: Sorry, you want your Mac to do nothing while it's sleeping, so you told it to do something while it's sleeping, but now you're confused that it's doing something while it's sleeping... have you tried not giving it tasks to do while it's sleeping?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I have closed all applications,  Activity Monitor show disk write 3GB, maybe still disk swapping.

Comment: What is the point of this? What are you seeking to achieve by trying to prevent swapping?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan No, I just want to reduce the number of ssd writes because the write caused by sleep is superfluous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `csrutil enable` will cause swapping mode reopen.

   edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist` file to disable it;

   [image]

   then restart the SIP mode.
2. Disable standby, autopoweroff, ttyskeepawake, tcpkeepalive in pmset:

   ```
   pmset -a standby 0
   pmset -a autopoweroff 0
   pmset -a ttyskeepawake 0
   pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0
   ```

Comment: What is "1. `csrutil enable` while cause swapping mode reopen." supposed to mean? It's not even a coherent sentence!

Comment: This seems to be a YZ-answer to a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @klanomath First thank you for edit the grammatical mistakes in my question. The above method does solve this problem, I am waiting for someone to provide a better one.

Comment: @aliasw The whole problem is somehow comparable to [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat). But: if you smash the box, the cat is dead for sure.

Comment: What is "1. `csrutil enable` while cause swapping mode reopen." supposed to mean? It's not even a coherent sentence! Additionally, the image you posted of the .plist file isn't at all clear what specific edit is to be made! You should have posted the text content not an image. While this incoherent answer may have solved your issue, as written it is a poor answer at best!